# Display different context menu

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

Goal:
Display different context menu if right clicking a row from the listview or right clicking inside of listview without making a selection of a row.

Problem:
Having difficult to find a solution that enable to display different context menu once clicking on something.

---

```
private void lstvdMonth_MouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{



    ContextMenu myContextMenu = new ContextMenu();;

    if (MouseButtonState.Released == e.RightButton)
    {


        MenuItem menuItem3 = new MenuItem();
        menuItem3.Header = "Add quantity";
        myContextMenu.Items.Add(menuItem3);
        menuItem3.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(menuItem3_Click);

        MenuItem menuItem2 = new MenuItem();
        menuItem2.Header = "Delete";
        myContextMenu.Items.Add(menuItem2);
        menuItem2.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(menuItem2_Click);
    }
    else
    {
        MenuItem menuItem1 = new MenuItem();
        menuItem1.Header = "New product";
        myContextMenu.Items.Add(menuItem1);
        menuItem1.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(menuItem1_Click);
    }

    myContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you should test in the `if` is whether any items are selected in the ListView (e.g. `SelectedItem == null`).

How exactly do you expect the mouse button to ever be down in the MouseUp event?

Comment: That is one of the problem I'm having. If you have a selection of a row in the list and then you go right click in a empty space inside of listview area. Then you can't do it cuz you already have made a selection. You have to deselect by using ctrl + left right mouse clickin in the list view to remove the selection mark.

When it is 'bout the technical perspective, I don't know but in this context I'm taking acccount to user interface as a number 1 and then I go dealing with technical issue.

Comment: I was enable to solve this problem by event "lstvdMonth_MouseRightButtonDown" and "lstvdMonth_MouseRightButtonUp"